# time series forecasting with breakup of variables

Tags: python, time-series

i am building a time series model where i want to predict number of defects and then breakup of those defects in some categories.
example:(2019 data)

```
month   num_defects   product_category supp_category
 jan19   10               cat1               supp1
 jan19   15               cat2               supp3
 feb19   24               cat3               supp2
```

if i predict number of defects in jun 2020 to be 45, then what should be breakup like above i.e cat1 will have 30 and cat2 will have 15 defects(sum:45) and supp1 will have 15 , supp2 will have 20 ...etc

so basically i want to predict the number of defects and their breakups.

i am using VAR model in predicting the time series.Just want to know the approach can anyone help me with

Comment: Could You elaborate a bit more, please. Provide data, code, expected result.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is specifically for programming, not for ML model design. There are many online resources for this (although if you are already using a VAR model then it looks like you have your approach...), including for example stats.stackexchange.com or https://datascience.stackexchange.com. Try searching there, you will probably find something useful - but search those sites (and google in general) before asking there. Good luck!

Comment: I agree with @ItamarMushkin. Please refer datascience.stackexchange.com or stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to datascience stack exchange.